# php reading from sockets

Tags: php, sockets

I need to communicate with service by sending and getting xml through socket.

```
...    
$fp = fsockopen("...", "..,", $errno, $errstr);
fwrite($fp, $xml);
echo stream_get_contents($fp);
```

but it's take too long to get output by stream_get_contents() 
on the other hand fpassthru() prints output immediately but than script stuck for a few seconds before ending.

Is there any way to get data from socket?

PS: I can't use fread() because of not knowing the length of the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go with fread - if you don't know the length of the response, just check for EOF in a loop:

```
    while (!feof($handle)) {
    $xml .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);
```

fread() - reading stops (non-exhaustive list) if one of following conditions are met:

1. length bytes have been read
2. EOF (end of file) is reached